# How to get the IP's lists who view the website hosted in AWS cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static website hosting on the AWS Cloudfront. I want to know the IP's Count and List for analysis purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Access Logs - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html):

> You can configure CloudFront to create **log files** that contain detailed information about every user request that CloudFront receives... If you enable logging, you can also specify the Amazon S3 bucket that you want CloudFront to save files in.